# SQL server Coordinate distance optimization

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, optimization, query-optimization, geospatial

I am working with `SQL server 2008` on query that looks for users within certain distance from central point that is moving - which means I am constantly hitting database (new results need to be added to the existing set and ones out of distance to be removed) and every millisecond saved is of value.

ATM we are using following query (Id's are used cause they are indexed ATM and good when trying for speed):

```
declare @lat int = 500,
@lon int = 700

  SELECT @lat, @lon, id, journeyid,  ((ACOS(SIN(@lat * PI() / 180) * SIN([Id] * PI() / 180) + 
         COS(@lat * PI() / 180) * COS([Id] * PI() / 180) * COS((@lon - [JourneyId]) * 
         PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) as dist
FROM [OnlineLegal_dev1].[dbo].[Customer] 
         group by [Id], [JourneyId], ((ACOS(SIN(@lat * PI() / 180) * SIN([Id] * PI() / 180) + 
         COS(@lat * PI() / 180) * COS([Id] * PI() / 180) * COS((@lon - [JourneyId]) * 
         PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515)
HAVING ((ACOS(SIN(@lat * PI() / 180) * SIN([Id] * PI() / 180) + 
         COS(@lat * PI() / 180) * COS([Id] * PI() / 180) * COS((@lon - [JourneyId]) * 
         PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515)<=10000

  ORDER BY ((ACOS(SIN(@lat * PI() / 180) * SIN([Id] * PI() / 180) + 
         COS(@lat * PI() / 180) * COS([Id] * PI() / 180) * COS((@lon - [JourneyId]) * 
         PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) ASC
```

Current speed to select top 1k records is 00:00:00.097

**How could I optimize this further for speed?**

Comment: Can you explain your formula, please (some spherical geometry I guess)? Taking the sinus of an ID looks very strange. Why can't you simply calculate the distance with Pythagoras?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Ids are used since those columns are indexed, it would be latitude longitude in actual app. It curves to account for the roundness of earth for coordinates further from equator. If this cannot be optimized well enough another option we might use is square that is multiplied by constant for country since we are based in Europe and countries are small here.

Comment: Any reason not to use the geography data type here and let the math be done in the CLR?

Comment: @BenThul TBH I never used it, still I find it hard to believe it could be faster than pure sql solution, am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you are. CLR excels at (among other things) doing calculation heavy things like you're doing. Also, you get the advantage of the geography type not assuming that the Earth is a perfect sphere (like the Haversine forumula that you're using does) but rather an oblate spheroid.

Comment: @BenThul Thanks, I will look into that.

Comment: @BenThul I did here are the results http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34763910/sql-geometry-vs-decimal8-6-lat-long-performance/34763914#34763914

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @lat INT = 500,
        @lon INT = 700

DECLARE @lat_s FLOAT = SIN(@lat * PI() / 180),
        @lat_c FLOAT = COS(@lat * PI() / 180)

SELECT DISTINCT @lat, @lon, *
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        journeyid,
        ((ACOS(@lat_s * SIN([id] * PI() / 180) + @lat_c * COS([id] * PI() / 180) * COS((@lon - [JourneyId]) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS dist
    FROM dbo.Customer
) t
WHERE dist <= 10000
ORDER BY dist
```

Comment: Very clever :) Oddly speed is the same, I will add more data for it to show.

Comment: After indexing and other jazz for 47k records to run 100 times selection of top 1000 where proximity is 10000 - mine is ~28s and yours ~16s.

Comment: A similar answer can be found https://stackoverflow.com/q/44293480/5058871

Answer (score 1):

You could store the pre-calculated values

```
SIN([Id] * PI() / 180)
```

and

```
COS([Id] * PI() / 180)
```

In the DB, for instance with an INSERT / UPDATE trigger each time an `Id` is inserted or updated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tiuCustomer ON dbo.Customer
    FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS BEGIN
   UPDATE dbo.Customer
   SET
       cos_id = COS(Inserted.Id * PI() / 180),
       sin_id = SIN(Inserted.Id * PI() / 180)
   FROM Inserted
   WHERE 
      dbo.Customer.CustomerID = Inserted.CustomerID -- Use the PK to link your table
                                                    -- with Inserted.
END
```