# SQL Geometry VS decimal(8,6) Lat, Long Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance, sqlgeography, geographic-distance

I was looking into performance of selecting closest points within certain proximity to given coordinate.

Options are to ether use two `decimal(8,6)` - lat, long columns or single `geography` column and work with that.

**I am only interested which is faster?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** Geography is ~10 times faster.

Ok so I have set up test:

Couple of tables one with `id,lat,long (int, decimal(8,6),decimal(8,6))` other with `id,coord (int, geography)`.

Then insert 47k of random data.

For indexing first table I used nonclustered Ascending index on lat,long with fill factor of 95.
 for second one `GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = LOW,LEVEL_2 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_3 = LOW,LEVEL_4 = LOW` with fill factor 95.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Temp
(
Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
Coord geography NOT NULL
)  ON [PRIMARY]
 TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Temp ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_Temp PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    Id
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


declare @i int =0
    declare @lat decimal(8,6) =0.0
      declare @long decimal(8,6) =0.0
  while (@i < 47000)
  begin
  set @lat =(select (0.9 -Rand()*1.8)*100)
 set @long =(select (0.9 -Rand()*1.8)*100)
    insert into Temp
  select geography::Point(@lat, @long,4326)


set @i =@i+1

 end

go


CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [SpatialIndex_1] ON [dbo].Temp
(
    [coord]
)USING  GEOGRAPHY_GRID 
WITH (GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = LOW,LEVEL_2 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_3 = LOW,LEVEL_4 = LOW), 
CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 16, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 95) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Temp2](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Lat] [decimal](8, 6) NOT NULL,
    [Long] [decimal](8, 6) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Temp2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


declare @i int = 0
declare @lat decimal(8,6)  = 0 
declare @long decimal(8,6)  = 0

while (@i < 47000)
begin
set @lat = (select (0.9 - (RAND()*1.8))*100)
set @long = (select (0.9 - (RAND()*1.8))*100)

insert into Temp2
select @lat , @long

set @i = @i +1
end

go
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Coord_IX] ON [dbo].[Temp2] 
(
    [Lat] ASC,
    [Long] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 95) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Then I ran couple of tests:

**First is for Lat,Long.**

```
declare @lat decimal(8,6) = 0.0,
 @lon decimal(8,6) = 0.0,
@i int = 0,
@start datetime = getdate()

while(@i < 100)
begin

set @lat =   (select (0.9 - Rand()*1.8)*100)
set @lon =  (select (0.9 - (RAND()*1.8))*100.0)

DECLARE @lat_s FLOAT = SIN(@lat * PI() / 180),
        @lat_c FLOAT = COS(@lat * PI() / 180)


SELECT DISTINCT top 1000 @lat, @lon, *
FROM (
    SELECT
        lat,
        long,
        ((ACOS(@lat_s * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + @lat_c * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS((@lon - long) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS dist
    FROM dbo.Temp2
) t
ORDER BY dist

set @i= @i+1
end
print CONVERT(varchar,(getdate()-@start),108)
go
```

**Second is for geography.**

```
 DECLARE @g geography;


   declare @point nvarchar(50)  =''
 declare @i int =0,
     @lat decimal(8,6) =0.0,
       @long decimal(8,6) =0.0,
       @start datetime = getdate()
  while (@i < 100)
  begin
  set @lat =(select (0.9 -Rand()*1.8)*100)
 set @long =(select (0.9 -Rand()*1.8)*100)
 set @point = (select 'POINT('+CONVERT(varchar(10), @lat)+ '  ' +CONVERT(varchar(10), @long)+')')
 SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText(@point, 4326);
    SELECT TOP 1000
    @lat,
    @long,
        @g.STDistance(st.[coord]) AS [DistanceFromPoint (in meters)] 
    ,   st.[coord]
    ,   st.id
FROM    Temp st 
ORDER BY @g.STDistance(st.[coord]) ASC

set @i =@i+1

 end
print CONVERT(varchar,(getdate()-@start),108)
 go
```

**Results:**

- Lat,Long - 00:00:10
- Geography - 00:02:21

For those who are wondering why geography has such poor performance 
here's execution plan - notice that it does not use spatial index, and takes ages to sort since row size is 4047 Bytes (against 25 Bytes in decimal). Trying [to force index results in runtime error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764637/query-processor-could-not-produce-a-query-plan-because-of-the-hints-defined-in-t)

[image]

**P.S** I also did one for flat surface but difference from spherical one is very small ~0.5s (comes back in 9.5-10.0 seconds which does seem to be slightly faster) still to have it all in one place here's script:

```
print 'flat'
declare @lat decimal(8,6) = 0.0,
 @lon decimal(8,6) = 0.0,
@i int = 0,
@start datetime = getdate()

while(@i < 100)
begin

set @lat =   (select (0.9 - Rand()*1.8)*100)
set @lon =  (select (0.9 - (RAND()*1.8))*100.0)

SELECT DISTINCT top 1000 @lat, @lon, *
FROM (
    SELECT
        lat,
        long,
        sqrt(power((@lat - lat),2) + (power((@lon - long),2))) AS dist
    FROM dbo.Temp2
) t

ORDER BY dist

set @i= @i+1
end
print CONVERT(varchar,(getdate()-@start),108)
go
```

**UPDATE:**

After switching to SQL 2014 and forcing to use the index with 10M records:

- Lat,Long took 00:00:22.935
- Flat took 00:00:22.988
- Geography took 00:00:02.427

geography script used:

```
DECLARE @g geography;
declare @point nvarchar(50)  =''
declare @i int =0,
        @lat decimal(8,6) =0.0,
        @long decimal(8,6) =0.0,
        @start datetime = getdate()
set @lat =(select (0.9 -Rand()*1.8)*100)
set @long =(select (0.9 -Rand()*1.8)*100)
set @point = (select 'POINT('+CONVERT(varchar(10), @lat)+ '  ' 
             +CONVERT(varchar(10), @long)+')')
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText(@point, 4326);

SELECT TOP 1000
    @lat,
    @long,
        @g.STDistance(st.[coord]) AS [DistanceFromPoint (in meters)] 
    ,   st.[coord]
    ,   st.id
FROM    Temp st with(index([SpatialIndex_1]))
WHERE @g.STDistance(st.[coord])  IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY @g.STDistance(st.[coord]) asc
```

Comment: So the TL;DR here is "the spatial index wasn't used and therefore the geography datatype didn't perform well". I'll try to repro this test later when I have a minute, but I would bet dollars to donuts that once the spatial index is in play that it perform much better. Kudos for trying to test empirically though!

Comment: @BenThul You were right - geography is faster, check update. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I've seen the optimizer choose not to use a spatial index when it clearly makes sense to use it. But I haven't been able to detect a pattern. I'm glad you found a more performant solution!