# Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query. Resubmit the query and without using SET FORCEPLAN

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, spatial-index, sqlgeography

I am running following:

```
DECLARE @g geography;
declare @point nvarchar(50)  =''
declare @i int =0,
        @lat decimal(8,6) =0.0,
        @long decimal(8,6) =0.0,
        @start datetime = getdate()
set @lat =(select (0.9 -Rand()*1.8)*100)
set @long =(select (0.9 -Rand()*1.8)*100)
set @point = (select 'POINT('+CONVERT(varchar(10), @lat)+ '  ' 
             +CONVERT(varchar(10), @long)+')')
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText(@point, 4326);
SELECT TOP 1000
    @lat,
    @long,
        @g.STDistance(st.[coord]) AS [DistanceFromPoint (in meters)] 
    ,   st.[coord]
    ,   st.id
FROM    Temp st with(index([SpatialIndex_1]))
```

this query performed poorly because it does not use spacial index, so I added `with(index([SpatialIndex_1]))` to force it.

geography index looks following:

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [SpatialIndex_1] ON [dbo].Temp
(
    [coord]
)USING  GEOGRAPHY_GRID 
WITH (GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = LOW,LEVEL_2 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_3 = LOW,LEVEL_4 = LOW), 
CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 16, PAD_INDEX = OFF,
STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 95) 
ON [PRIMARY]
```

Now it gives me error message

> Msg 8622, Level 16, State 1, Line 15 Query processor could not
>   produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query.
>   Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET
>   FORCEPLAN.

I can read and understand that it tells me to remove hint, question is why does it succeed at compilation but fails on run-time? Is there something wrong with my index?

**What do I need to change for SQL to start using Spatial index?**

to generate some data you could use following script.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Temp
    (
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    Coord geography NOT NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
     TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Temp ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_Temp PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    Id
    ) 
WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
ON [PRIMARY]
GO


declare @i int =0
declare @lat decimal(8,6) =0.0
declare @long decimal(8,6) =0.0
while (@i < 47000)
begin
   set @lat =(select (0.9 -Rand()*1.8)*100)
   set @long =(select (0.9 -Rand()*1.8)*100)
   insert into Temp
   select geography::Point(@lat, @long,4326)
   set @i =@i+1
end
go

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [SpatialIndex_1] ON [dbo].Temp
(
    [coord]
)USING  GEOGRAPHY_GRID 
WITH (GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = LOW,LEVEL_2 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_3 = LOW,LEVEL_4 = LOW), 
   CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 16, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
   SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF,
   ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 95) 
ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929109.aspx):

The following requirements must be met for a Nearest Neighbor query to use a spatial index:

1. A spatial index must be present on one of the spatial columns and
   the STDistance() method must use that column in the WHERE and ORDER
   BY clauses.
2. The TOP clause cannot contain a PERCENT statement.
3. The WHERE clause must contain a STDistance() method.
4. If there are multiple predicates in the WHERE clause then the
   predicate containing STDistance() method must be connected by an AND
   conjunction to the other predicates. The STDistance() method cannot
   be in an optional part of the WHERE clause.
5. The first expression in the ORDER BY clause must use the
   STDistance() method.
6. Sort order for the first STDistance() expression in the ORDER BY
   clause must be ASC.
7. All the rows for which STDistance returns NULL must be filtered out.

So, this should work:

```
DECLARE @g geography;
declare @point nvarchar(50)  =''
declare @i int =0,
        @lat decimal(8,6) =0.0,
        @long decimal(8,6) =0.0,
        @start datetime = getdate()
set @lat =(select (0.9 -Rand()*1.8)*100)
set @long =(select (0.9 -Rand()*1.8)*100)
set @point = (select 'POINT('+CONVERT(varchar(10), @lat)+ '  ' 
             +CONVERT(varchar(10), @long)+')')
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText(@point, 4326);

SELECT TOP 1000
    @lat,
    @long,
        @g.STDistance(st.[coord]) AS [DistanceFromPoint (in meters)] 
    ,   st.[coord]
    ,   st.id
FROM    Temp st with(index([SpatialIndex_1]))
WHERE @g.STDistance(st.[coord])  IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY @g.STDistance(st.[coord]) asc
```

You can check that it is using the spacial index even the `WITH INDEX` hint is removed.

Comment: I was ordering (just wanted the nearest TOP x), but didn't have a where clause with STDistance() in there; cleared it up for me. Thanks man.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, i moved the database from one db to another and i forgot about the db Indexes migration.

create the indexes in the new db and solved the problem

Comment: This IS the cause of my issue, missing indexes. Once I compared the schemas and recreated  missing indexes, the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I had got a same type of exception when I was trying to run Hangfire and the exception was

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET FORCEPLAN

I have fixed this issue by doing two simple steps:

1. Firstly, I find a HEAP table i.e. a table without clustered index using query

   SELECT SCH.name + '.' + TBL.name AS TableName FROM sys.tables AS TBL
   INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS SCH ON TBL.schema_id = SCH.schema_id
   INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS IDX ON TBL.object_id = IDX.object_id AND IDX.type = 0
   ORDER BY TableName
2. Secondly, I have created a clustered index on all tables that I got in result of above query