# Cannot update Entity Framework Edmx from Database in Visual Studio 2022 17.7.4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2022, edmx

We have an Entity Framework Edmx file comprising our database tables, and we added a new table. When trying to add this table to the Edmx file via the (Update Model from Database...) option and after choosing the required table, I get an error message in Entity Data Model Output:

```
Unable to generate the model because of the following exception: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET FORCEPLAN.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.Execute(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader.LoadDataTable[T](String sql, Func`2 orderByFunc, DataTable table, EntityStoreSchemaFilterObjectTypes queryTypes, IEnumerable`1 filters, String[] filterAliases)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader.LoadTableDetails(IEnumerable`1 filters)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader.LoadStoreSchemaDetails(IList`1 filters)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.GetStoreSchemaDetails(StoreSchemaConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.CreateStoreModel()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.GenerateModel(List`1 errors)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelBuilderEngine.GenerateModel(ModelBuilderSettings settings, IVsUtils vsUtils, ModelBuilderEngineHostContext hostContext)'.
```

Of course, we are not using any query plans, and we have no idea how to fix this problem.
We are using Visual Studio 2022 17.7.4.

Did anyone face such an issue?

We tried to add the entity of the table the manual way but couldn't because the entity must be mapped to a table, which we cannot add.

Edit: there was an update today to Visual Studio, which updated the version to 17.7.5, but the issue still exists.
I had to add the table and the entity manually to the file, and we will test if it is working.

Comment: [To use a spatial index for nearest neighbor query, the following requirements must be met](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34766270/20376806) mentioned this issue. According to [Query Spatial Data for Nearest Neighbor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/query-spatial-data-for-nearest-neighbor?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN), the table you add must meet the requirements in the document. If these possibilities are ruled out, you can try temporarily removing any custom queries or stored procedures associated with the new tables and updating the model.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. We use tables only with no stored procedures and all our indexes are normal, no spatial data is used at all.

Comment: If the table that uses the stored procedure is not used, will it work to temporarily delete the association between the table and the table? Is there any progress on your issue?